# Rails - Make association check boxes appear in drop down list instead of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, associations, simple-form, dropdown

I'm using the simple_form gem to render checkboxes. Here's my code:

```
<tr>
  <th>Authors</th>
    <td><%= f.association :authors, as: :check_boxes, label: false %></td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that my collection is showing up in an array like this: 
[image: terrible for UX!!]

How do I get this array of checkboxes to be in dropdown format instead?

Comment: From the documentation, you can pass a block to `f.association` (https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L181) so you could pass a block with the check_box, the label and then a `<br>`. If you want something more complex (like 3 columns of evenly distributed checkbox+label) you will need to manually loop over those possible authors.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution! I discovered [this blog post](http://blog.planetargon.com/entries/block-radios-and-checkboxes-with-simple_form) and used the `item_wrapper_tag:` helper, which I used on my `f.association` code. That allowed me to put a div around the series of checkboxes. Then I gave it a class so I could use CSS to style this div with `inline-block`.

```
<tr>
  <th>Authors</th>
    <td><%= f.association :authors, as: :check_boxes, item_wrapper_tag: :div, item_wrapper_class: "inline_block", label: false %></td>
</tr>
```

Which produced this result. The content is now in a vertical list instead of an array.

[image]

I'll need to poke around a little more with the CSS to contain it within a scrollable box, but overall this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [collection_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)?

Would look something like this:

```
<%= collection_select(:author, :name, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true) %>
```

Hope it helps,
Cheers